# GUI testing tool

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

which is the best GUI testing tool that could possibly workout in **all the browsers**. Something that could generate the scripts and those scripts can be reused in other applications for re-execution.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is no testing tool that can drive every browser.

Comment: but the thing is like my application work only on IE8 and those application that we test works on firefox. I guess tools like selenium works only on firefox browser. :( in tat case, how is tat possible for me to integrate selenium with my application which supports only IE8?

Comment: If your target platform is IE8 and only IE8, why are you looking for a testing tool that supports every browser instead of one that supports IE8?

Comment: I will make it clear. My application is used as a testing tool tat test other applications running on various browsers.The new requirement is tat, I need to integrate selenium with my app in order to automate the testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [WebDriver](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium).

Comment: so what is the difference between selenium IDE and RC? I don't find tutorials so clear anywhere.

Comment: @ShaliniViswanath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605761/understanding-selenium-ide-vs-selenium-rc

Answer (score 0):

there are some links that can help you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120359/tools-for-automated-gui-testing-on-windows