# Selenium file upload leaves file selector window open (OS/X and Python)

Tags: python, macos, selenium, file-upload, selenium-webdriver

I'm able to upload a file to a remote server using Selenium, but the file selector dialog sticks around even once the file is uploaded. [The Selenium FAQ notes that](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-does-webdriver-support-file-uploads), "You can't interact with the native OS file browser dialog directly, but we do some magic so that...." Given the use of "magic" here it's not surprising that the behavior I get is a little rough around the edges. But there appear to be workarounds. Taking my cues from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864547/2829764) I have the following code:

```
import contextlib, time
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains as action_chains
with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Chrome()) as driver:
    driver.get("http://www.bing.com/images")
    driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_t").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_file").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_file_upload").send_keys("//Loch Ness Monster.jpg")
    print driver.current_url # Still `http://www.bing.com/images` :(
    file_upload = driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_file_upload")
    action_chains.ActionChains(driver).click(file_upload).perform() # https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864547/2829764
```

But at the end of this the file upload window is still there. I suspect I need a slightly different workaround since I'm on a Mac. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't click upload button at all.

Set the filename via `send_keys()` and click "Go" (tested and works for me):

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_file_upload")
element.send_keys('/Path/to/file.jpeg')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#sbi_sb_ipt span[name=go]').click()
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! I had to comment out the last line to avoid `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` but the code is working fine without it.