# Simple file upload snippet in Selenium works in Chrome but not Firefox on my Mac

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, selenium

Courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28801842/2829764) I've got this bit of Selenium working:

```
import contextlib
from selenium import webdriver

with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Chrome()) as driver:
    driver.get("http://www.bing.com/images")
    driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_t").click()
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_file_upload")
    element.send_keys("//Loch Ness Monster.jpg")
```

However, when I switch from `webdriver.Chrome()` to `webdriver.Firefox()`, I start getting `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`. My guess is that the error is related to the magic that Selenium performs to work with operating system file upload selector dialogs. I would think that's probably also why my attempts to wait until the element becomes visible aren't working: the "magic" does not involve the element ever becoming visible. Here's what I tried:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/15142611/2829764, found via https://stackoverflow.com/q/6101461/2829764
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
...
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "sbi_file_upload")))
```

I'm using Firefox 36.0.1, Selenium 2.45.0, and Python 2.7.9. Incidentally, Selenium had stopped working with Firefox when I updated Firefox to 36.0.1 but I updated my Selenium today and the particular problem I was having went away.

Comment: which firefox version do you use? 35?

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov, I've added version info to the question. I'm using Firefox 36.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element you are sending keys to has an opacity value set to `0`:

```
<input id="sbi_file_upload" name="imageBinary" type="file" accept="image/*" style="opacity: 0;">
```

And `Firefox` (correctly) thinks *the element is invisible*:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get("http://www.bing.com/images")
>>> driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_t").click()
>>> element = driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_file_upload")
>>> element.is_displayed()
False
```

Here are the relevant issues that actually are the reason for the behavior we see:

- [Selenium allows to sendKeys into an invisible input type=file](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7625)
- [With Firefox can not upload file to hidden field](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8138)

---

The solution here would be to **make the `input` visible** so that we can send the keys to it. I've found a rather weird way to make the input visible - it involves sending an empty file value first, going back and making the `input` visible through `execute_script()`. Hope, you'll make it work without an extra `back()` step:

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get('http://www.bing.com/images')
>>> driver.maximize_window()
>>> 
>>> driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_t").click()
>>> 
>>> button = driver.find_element_by_id('sbi_gh')
>>> driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display = "block";', button)
>>> button.click()  # submitting the form, empty file
>>> 
>>> driver.back()
>>> driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_t").click()
>>> 
>>> file_input = driver.find_element_by_id('sbi_file_upload')
>>> file_input.is_displayed()
False
>>> 
>>> driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style = ""; arguments[0].style.display = "block"; arguments[0].style.visibility = "visible";', file_input)
>>> 
>>> file_input.is_displayed()
True
```

And now you can send keys to file input - tested, works for me.

Comment: @kuzzooroo could you also check with selenium 2.44 and firefox 34.0.5?

Comment: @kuzzooroo we should have figured that before - this is a security feature - we cannot set the value of a file input like this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html. I guess our only option right now is to make the input visible so that we can send keys to it via `send_keys()`..

Comment: @kuzzooroo or, yes, try with downgrading selenium and firefox as noted in previous comments. I don't like this option, but we would have at least an option if it works.

Comment: @kuzzooroo sorry, this somehow worked for me once :) There was probably smth else I did manually in the browser, investigating..

Comment: @kuzzooroo please see the update - this is working for me, hope it would for you also. And hope that you'll find a way to simplify the approach. But, at least, we have a solution here.

Comment: @alexce, I found that I had to make a few tweaks to get the code working consistently on my machine. For now I've pasted the result in as an answer below.

Comment: @kuzzooroo great, thanks for sharing! It was an interesting challenge

Answer (score 2):

Lightly modified version of @alexce's answer. It's the only thing I've found that works consistently on my machine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import selenium

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.bing.com/images')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "sbi_t")))
driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_t").click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "sbi_file_upload")))
    raise Exception("This never seems to happen")
except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
    pass

button = driver.find_element_by_id('sbi_gh')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display = "block";', button)
button.click()  # submitting the form, empty file
driver.back()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "sbi_t")))
driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_t").click()
file_input = driver.find_element_by_id('sbi_file_upload')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style = ""; arguments[0].style.display = "block"; arguments[0].style.visibility = "visible";', file_input)
file_input.send_keys("//Loch Ness Monster.jpg")
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution 'make the element visible in firefox '
was great for me

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style = ""; 
arguments[0].style.display = "block"; 
arguments[0].style.visibility = "visible";', file_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This , If `is_displayed()` method gives an exception

```
from selenium import  webdriver

def is_Displayed(class_name):
    ele=driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('"+class_name+"')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';")
    if ele=="visible":
        return True
    else:
        return False

def test_check_element():
    global driver
    driver=webdriver.Safari()//e.g Firefox() , Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get("url")
    submitBtn=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Submit']").get_attribute("class")


    if is_Displayed(submitBtn)== True:
        print "Displayed "
    else:
        print "Not Displayed"
```

Comment: is_dispayed() issue only with Safari 10 and not with Safari 5.1+